# Python input always returns a string

Tags: python, visual-studio

I ran this code through Visual Studio Code:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    max_count = input('enter an int:  ') 
    if max_count.isdigit():
        break
    print('sorry, try again')

max_count = int(max_count)  

while counter < max_count:
    print(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
```

And was very surprised to see this response:

```
python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"                                   
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"            
enter an int:  5                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                        
  File "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py", line 7, in <module>              
    if max_count.isdigit():                                                                               
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Because input() is always supposed to return a string:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input

I put in a quoted string:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"            
enter an int:  '5'
0                                                                         
1
2
3
4
```

and now it works as expected.  Then I ran it on my standard issue Ubuntu terminal:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python$ python3 flatnested.py
enter an int:  5
0
1
2
3
4
```

And it worked as expected, note no quotes around the 5.

What's going on here? Has Visual Studio Code 'rewritten' the rules of Python?

Comment: In your first case, you appear to be running under Python 2.7. The `input()` function changed between version 2.7 and version 3 - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

It appears that when you run the code through Visual Studio Code, Python 2.7 is being used to run the code.

If you wish to continue using Python 2.7, use the `raw_input` instead of the `input` function.

**Explanation**

Take a look at the Python 2.7 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) for the input function. It's different from the input function used in Python 3.x. In Python 2.7, the input function uses the `eval` function to process the input the program receives as though the input were a line of Python code.

```
python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"                                   
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"            
enter an int:  5                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                        
  File "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py", line 7, in <module>              
    if max_count.isdigit():                                                                               
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

What's happening in the case above, with Python 2.7, is:

`eval("5").isdigit() # 5.isdigit()`

The above Python statement is invalid, because it results in trying to call an `.isdigit()` method on an integer. But, integers in Python do not have that method.

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ python "/home/malikarumi/Documents/PYTHON/Blaikie Python/flatnested.py"            
enter an int:  '5'
0                                                                         
1
2
3
4
```

In the case above, with Python 2.7, what's happening is:

`eval("'5'").isdigit() # '5'.isdigit()`

The statement above is valid because it results in a string calling a `.isdigit()` method, which does exist for strings.

I hope this answers your question and gives you a clearer understanding of the differences between the `input` functions in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

Comment: You both gave good answers but yours was a little more detailed so I gave you the points. Thanks, I knew raw_input() had become input() going from 2 to 3, but I did not know 2 had its own input() that was different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu (or others LINUX distro), when typing `python` in terminal, it equals with `python2`, so the first time you run with `python`, you're using Python 2, instead of Python 3, that error is obvious. 
The reason why you put quote string and it worked because in Python 2, `input()` is equal `eval(raw_input())`

```
>>> input()
5 
5
# equal with eval(5), which is 5
```

With quote string

```
>>> input()
'5'
'5'
# equal with eval('5'), which is '5'
```

In second time it worked as expected since you explicitly run with `python3`